# Parse Local Datastore - How to sync

Tags: ios, parse-platform, synchronization

I am trying to use the parse local datastore on my app.
 Our DB contains large images and part of the agreed design is to download everything
at the start of the app while showing an animation.

Everything is well, now my concern is how to update the local datastore without downloading 
everything again?

Is there a parse way to do this?

Comment: How often do the images change? How big is the image store - 10 Megs, 100 Megs, etc? With a little more info I can suggest an optimal solution.

Comment: +/- 3MB, update can be every after 2 weeks. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `PFConfig` to set a version number on the image set. Every time you update the images, increment the images version number.

When the app starts, have it run `[PFConfig synchronize]` and check to see if the image set has changed. If there is an image set update, download the new image set and store locally as pinned objects. One download per user per set, updates regularly and automatically.